# Issue in appending php variable in sql query

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the following query

```
SELECT  `meta_value`-0.2
FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'latitude' 
AND `post_id` =(SELECT  wp_posts.ID 
                FROM  wp_posts 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
                WHERE  wp_posts.post_content LIKE  '%$searched%'
                    OR  wp_posts.post_title LIKE  '%$searched%'
                    OR  wp_posts.post_name LIKE  '%$searched%'
                    OR  wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$searched%'
                LIMIT 0 , 1 )
LIMIT  0 , 1
```

And the variable searched is also set by $searched = the_search_query();
But when I try to run the query there is nothing in searched variable

Comment: 1) The query you posted would error out, because a space is missing before `WHERE`, 2) Your `LIKE` expressions are most likely missing an intended `%` sign, and 3) You didn't post the actual PHP code, rather just a snippet which is out of context.

Comment: use '%$searched%'  instead of  '".$searched."'

Comment: Also, read about parametrised queries

Comment: Incidentally, I find the logic of `LEFT JOIN x....WHERE...OR x...` puzzling - but maybe that's just me

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 1) It was typo on the question 2)I added % but no result 3)I posted the code which is appropriate for the question 
There is a Select clause before it and a LEFT JOIN caluse which joins the postmeta table with posts table

Comment: No, you didn't show us entire PHP code.  In other words, you didn't post a raw SQL query, you posted what you cut and pasted from PHP.  This makes is very hard to tell what is going on, but in any case you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not adding the full raw query as it is too long. Yes I have edited the query to make some relevancy